# Time Complexities of an Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

What could be the best or easiest way for analyzing/solving time complexity of a program? Both for iterative and recursive methods. Thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Comment: This tread has some discussion about the topic of your question: [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Count how many times your basic operation will be executed.
For example:

```
int a = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    a += 1;
}
```

your basic operation is `a+=1`. so how many times will it be executed? for the example, `5`. Now instead of 5, we use `n`. so how many times will your basic operation execute? `n` times. then you can say the time complexity is `O(n)`. This also goes for the recursive methods.

Comment: Thanks for this.

Comment: you can mark the answer check if you think it is what you're looking for, or a vote up would be good. :)